# angularjs $watch, are variables removed after a template navigation

Tags: angularjs

I am a bit of a beginner, but I would like to ask a general question.  AngularJS does a watch on binded variables.  My question is, when I navigate and a new html template is loaded, are the old watched values removed, or do they stay in the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello **$watch** is bound to a controller ,which in turn shows the data to an HTML template.
So, If you navigate to another **state** or **url** and another controller loads , then the previous controller with all the data and the **$watch** will be unloaded, but new ones($watch) will load from the new loaded controller(if there are any).

Answer (score 0):

$watch are never removed by itself, they have to be removed manually.

You should go through $watch lifecycle : [$watch life cycle](http://onehungrymind.com/notes-on-angularjs-scope-life-cycle/)

Answer (score 0):

No, the $watch list is updated as per the html which is being rendered by the browser.If you change template inside the page, the browser will have to render the new expression.

I think [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fzWtSdgwgzU) would help you in getting